# I was trying to add templates to my Django project but it returns an error: TemplateDoesNotExist at /

Tags: python, django

I get a mistake when tying to add templates to my Django project.

settings.py :

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'),
)
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    a = models.User.objects.get()
    return render(request, "main/list.html", {"list": a})
```

and list.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Chats{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% if list%}
    {% for i in list%}
    <h2>{{i.usrname}}</h2>
{% endif %}
```

The project folder itself looks like this:

[image: Main is the app]

Main folder  is app.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am really not sure about this one, but I believe you should add a slash after templates : `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/')`

Answer (score 1):

You should include the `os.path.join(...)` in the Template 'DIRS'

Example:

In settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Then in your folder structure, you should have

```
app_name (main app folder) --> templates --> app_name(again) --> templates go here.
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention that in order to do this you must `import os`

Comment: error in BASE_DIR variable: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: @DaniilsKoselevs Did you `import os`?

Comment: Everything I have found with that type of error looks like it has to do with a problem with the import. Maybe make a separate question and someone else can help you find why you are getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

treid change TEMPLATE_DIRS completly with this

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            
            
        ],
    },
},
]
```